# How to create a repository in github.com using gitpython package

Tags: github, gitpython

I have tried to create a repository in github with my python program. I found gitpython package in web-search. I can able to pull repository but unable to create a repository in github. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Git and GitHub are different things.

The former is an open source distributed version control system. The latter is a commercial entity that provides products and services supportng Git. (Confusingly, it is also the name of many of those products.)

There is no way to create a repository on GitHub using the standard `git` command-line tool.

From [GitPython's PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/1.0.1):

> **GitPython** is a python library used to interact with Git repositories.

No mention is made of GitHub, and in general `git` and GitPython can do basically the same things. If you want to create a repository on GitHub you could use any of the libraries [listed here](https://developer.github.com/libraries/).

Alternatively, you could [use their API directly](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create), by `POST`ing to `/user/repos`. This method will require you to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), and in my opinion using one of the libraries from the previous list is easier and more robust.